# How to remove all FIFO files with a shell command

Tags: shell, command-line, rm, fifo

I can't find a shell command to remove all the FIFO files inside a directory. In fact, for the removal of directories, the `rm` command offers the options `-d, --dir`, but for FIFOs it offers no option.

For now, the only workaround found is to call the FIFO like `foo.fifo` so that it is easy to remove them with `rm *.fifo`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To delete all FIFOs in the current directory and all sub-folders use

```
find . -type p -delete
```

To delete FIFOs only in the current directory use

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -type p -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

shell only for current directory...

```
set -- ./*
for f do
    [ -p "$f" ] && rm "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type p -exec rm {} \;
```

Manpage of `find`:

```
-type c
      File is of type c:

      p      named pipe (FIFO)
```